# Mysterious jQuery AJAX bug wants more arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox

I user jQuery's ajax to sign up users.  I use almost the exact code below to do similar stuff all over my site and yet for some reason the code below is throwing this error in Firebug.

Error:

`uncaught exception: [Exception... "Not enough arguments" nsresult: "0x80570001 (NS_ERROR_XPC_NOT_ENOUGH_ARGS)" location: "JS frame :: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js :: add :: line 5437" data: no]`

Call:

```
lzaUserAPI.doAUserSignup(signupUsername, signupPassword, signupEmail, signupFullname, signupCompanyName, signupWebsite, signupPhone, lzaSigninup.onAUserSignedUp);
```

Ajax Function:

```
doAUserSignup : function(username, password, email, fullname, companyname, website, phone, callback){

    // Add to server
    var paras = {cmd : 'doAUserSignup', us: username, ps: password, em: email, flnm: fullname, cpnm: companyname, wbst: website, phne: phone};

    $.ajax({
        url: lzaUserAPI.m_url,
        dataType: "json",
        data: paras,
        success: function(ret){callback(ret)}
    });
},
```

Callback:

```
onAUserSignedUp : function (ret) {

    alert ('yea!!!');
    //Todo: log them in
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't find anything wrong with this. Can you put it up on a test server so we can look?

Comment: Sorry figured that out and removed comment but then saw your answer

Comment: @Amir, sorry - right now I don't have a test server going.  One extra clue is that commenting out `$.ajax({
        url: lzaUserAPI.m_url,
        dataType: "json",
        data: paras,
        success: function(ret){callback(ret)}
    });` makes it not throw the error.  :)  Any leads I can pursue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is somewhere in the code that converts the data object.  Since we can't see all the code where exactly is not clear.  Here is what you do, change the code like this:

```
// var paras = {cmd : 'doAUserSignup', us: username, ps: password, em: email, flnm: fullname, cpnm: companyname, wbst: website, phne: phone};
var paras = {cmd : 'doAUserSignup'};
```

See if that works, if it does start adding elements in till you find the problem.

Comment: i am curious if this works because it doesn't make sense then why commenting out the ajax call it throws no error.

Comment: !  That totally worked to debug it.  Turned out that one of the parameters was being passed in as a DOM object rather than a value, but until I did what you suggested it was too hard to spot in the code.  Thanks!!

Comment: @Emile : Great -- look at the code I could see it was something in the conversion...

Comment: Thanks, I had almost the same problem and this helped me fix it!  I was passing a jQuery object as my data, instead of an array, and that was causing the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this would fix anything but you should change:

```
success: function(ret){callback(ret)}
```

to

```
success: callback
```

Because you already have the callback as a pointer. No reason to make it wrapped with another.

Comment: I saw this too, but you should change it to `success: callback(ret)` right?

Comment: no, when calling a function you do callback() when passing a function to another, you do callback, without the ().

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up to anyone who encounters this... i looked for the reason that this happened for 2 hours before realizing i forgot to add the

```
.attr('value')
```

At the and of each value :(

**Meaning i did this:**

```
user_name: $('div#registrationForm').find('input#user_name'),
first_name: $('div#registrationForm').find('input#first_name'),
```

**Instead of this:**

```
user_name: $('div#registrationForm').find('input#user_name').attr('value'),
first_name: $('div#registrationForm').find('input#first_name').attr('value'),
```

Hope this helps to save someone the time!
Best Regards, Sagive